# Quickbook online auto-login

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We have a user dashboard and we are using QuickBooks PHP DevKit (https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) to add invoices in QuickBook.

We want to have a link in our user dashboard clicking which the user will auto-login to QuickBooks Online. Let us know how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't.

QuickBooks Online does not offer a way to automatically log in to it.

The closest you get is OpenID (which allows single-sign-on across QuickBooks Online and your app), which is documented here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/javascript_functions

And the "Connect to QuickBooks" button, which makes you click a button *ONCE* to get connected to QuickBooks Online, after which you can exchange data with QuickBooks Online *without* having to have the user log in from that point forward.

If you follow the quick-start it shows you how to do this:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php
- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start
- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3